# Video of Terence Tao on Poincaré's Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, advice

Last year, I found a video of Terence Tao on the Poincaré Conjecture, which could be downloaded in mp4 format. I did downloaded it, however I had to format my computer, then I lost it. I searched in Google, however, I could not find it again.

If anybody has it, please answer the link in this topic, or if you have downloaded it, please upload it here.

I am sorry if this kind of question does not match MSE question style.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found it [here](http://www.unisa.edu.au/austms2009/videos/default.asp). His blog also covers it [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/04/01/285g-lecture-2-the-ricci-flow-approach-to-the-poincare-conjecture/).

Comment: It has moved to here http://w3.unisa.edu.au/austms2009/videos/default.asp

Comment: Neither video link is working...